# Unable to bind volume folder inside docker container in an automated way through powershell script

Tags: powershell-remoting, docker-for-windows

i'm new to docker. i'm trying to automate things. I have a powershell script which will create a AWS windows instance, install docker and pull image from docker hub. I'm trying to bind the volume to docker container so that i can move the files from container to local machine in an automated way.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $r {docker volume create volume01}
Invoke-Command -Session $r {docker pull 474614/my_repo:javaprogram}
Invoke-Command -Session $r {docker images}
Invoke-Command -Session $r {docker run --name test01 -it -v c:\programdata\docker\volumes\volume01:c:\volume01 474614/my_repo:Accessibility cmd}
```

i get shown the below error:

```
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (the input devic...d with 'winpty':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : ec2-52-28-216-45.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

i tried running the command as below:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $r {winpty docker run --name test01 -it -v c:\programdata\docker\volumes\volume01:c:\volume01
```

i get shown:

```
winpty : The term 'winpty' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ winpty docker run --name test01 -it -v c:\programdata\docker\volumes\ ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (winpty:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Docker version:

PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

if winpty is required to run docker on non TTY device. how would i download the winpty for windows server 2016 through powershell. Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.